# Controller action called twice from Ajax post

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, action

It's been hours I'm searching for a solution.
I'm developing a C# and ASP.NET application using MVC.
It's a direct mail management application. I have a page that searches for duplicates in the companies database, then displays it in a list.
Then, when the user clicks on the company name, he lands on a page that displays the duplicates for this company.

To do so, on the search page I made an Ajax request to my controller action "Fiche", which will use the parameters sent to build the request and return the viewmodel filled with the company's duplicates.

The action is called once, with the right parameters, but then, it's called twice, with parameters set to false for the booleans and null for the string. So, I don't manage to retrieve the duplicates for the company.
Here is my click event :

```
$(a).click(function () {
        //some code that sets the variables used in cc
        var cc = {
            rsoc: raison_sociale,
            adr1: adresse,
            cp: code_postal,
            ville: ville_entreprise,
            tel: telephone,
            mail: e_mail,
            user_id: code_cotisant,
            profileConf: sessionStorage.getItem('categ')
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Fiche", "Doublons")",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ cc: cc, rsoc: $(this).text() }),
            success: function(response) {
                response ? alert("It worked!") : alert("It didn't work.");
            }
        });
    })
```

Here is my controller action :

```
public ActionResult Fiche(CompareConfiguration cc, string rsoc)
    {
        bool categorie = cc.profileConf != null ? true : false;
        Models.Entreprise entreprise = new Models.Entreprise();
        DataTable dt_doublons = new DataTable();
        if (rsoc != null)
        {
            dt_doublons = entreprise.search_doublons(cc.Rsoc, cc.Adr1, cc.CP, cc.Ville, cc.Tel, cc.Mail, cc.User_Id, categorie, cc.profileConf.Split(','));
            for (int i = 0; i < dt_doublons.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if(rsoc != dt_doublons.Rows[i]["rsoc"].ToString())
                {
                    dt_doublons.Rows[i].Delete();
                }
            }
            dt_doublons.AcceptChanges();
        }

        return View(getDoublons(dt_doublons));
    }

    private DoublonsViewModel getDoublons(DataTable dt_doublons)
    {
        DoublonsViewModel dblVM = new DoublonsViewModel()
        {
            ListeDoublons = new List<EntrepriseAndContacts>(),
            dt_doublons = dt_doublons
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < dt_doublons.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            EntrepriseAndContacts eac = new EntrepriseAndContacts();

            eac.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dt_doublons.Rows[i]["id_entreprise"]);
            eac.Rsoc = dt_doublons.Rows[i]["rsoc"].ToString();
            eac.nb_doublons = Convert.ToInt32(dt_doublons.Rows[i]["nb_doublons"]);
            eac.Etat_entreprise = Convert.ToInt32(dt_doublons.Rows[i]["importee"]);
            eac.Etat_contact = Convert.ToInt32(dt_doublons.Rows[i]["importe"]);
            eac.User_id = dt_doublons.Rows[i]["user_id"].ToString();
            eac.CVI = dt_doublons.Rows[i]["cvi"].ToString();
            eac.Nom = dt_doublons.Rows[i]["nom"].ToString();
            eac.Prenom = dt_doublons.Rows[i]["prenom"].ToString();
            eac.Mail = dt_doublons.Rows[i]["mail"].ToString();

            dblVM.ListeDoublons.Add(eac);
        }

        return dblVM;
    }
```

And the link :

```
foreach (var doublon in Model.ListeDoublons)
  {
    <tr>
      <td class="center size-15 height-25">
        <a href="@Url.Content("~/Doublons/Fiche")">@doublon.Rsoc</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center size-15 height-25">@doublon.nb_doublons</td>
    </tr>
  }
```

I tried to return false or to preventDefault on the click event but the view "Fiche" wasn't loaded anymore so it's not a solution in this case. I must be doing something wrong !

Edit : I've added [HttpPost] before my action but now the view isn't found.

Comment: `$(a)` can you share code where variable `a` is being initialized? Or have you configured to api via ajax POST request for each hyperlink click? One solution is to add a css class on hyperlink markup and then restrict the ajax post call to be initiated only when the hyperlinks with that specific css class are clicked e.g. `$('a.classname')`

Comment: @Mohsin Mehmood the event handler is added for each hyperlink, so the click event fires when whatever link is clicked, retrieving the name of the company (text of the link clicked)

Comment: How about doing something like this:
`<a href="@Url.Content("~/Doublons/Fiche")" class="doublon">@doublon.Rsoc</a>` and then `$('a.doublon').click(..)`

Comment: I could, but I'm not sure it's the source of the problem

Comment: This is most likely caused by the browser eager-fetching the links. Chrome has this feature turned on by default I think. So Chrome will automatically fetch the links to speed up the browsing. I suggest you to not use `a href` to post data.

Comment: Then how can I post data?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this time I can post an answer because I found a solution to my problem.
I removed the [HttpPost] before the action Fiche and while passing in the method for the first time, I stored the parameters cc and rsoc in two session variables. Then, I reassign it to cc and rsoc, so when it passes in the method for the second time with cc and rsoc empty, it retrieves them by the session. It's not a nice solution but I've got no time left and it works.

```
public ActionResult Fiche(CompareConfiguration cc, string rsoc)
    {
        if(cc.Adr1 != false || cc.Rsoc != false || cc.CP != false || cc.Ville != false || cc.Tel != false || cc.Mail != false || cc.User_Id != false)
        {
            Session["cc"] = cc;
            Session["rsoc_entreprise"] = rsoc;
        }

        cc = (CompareConfiguration)Session["cc"];
        rsoc = Session["rsoc_entreprise"].ToString();
        bool categorie = cc.profileConf != null ? true : false;
        Models.Entreprise entreprise = new Models.Entreprise();
        DataTable dt_doublons = new DataTable();
        if (rsoc != null)
        {
            dt_doublons = entreprise.search_doublons(cc.Rsoc, cc.Adr1, cc.CP, cc.Ville, cc.Tel, cc.Mail, cc.User_Id, categorie, cc.profileConf.Split(','));
            for (int i = 0; i < dt_doublons.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if(rsoc != dt_doublons.Rows[i]["rsoc"].ToString())
                {
                    dt_doublons.Rows[i].Delete();
                }
            }
            dt_doublons.AcceptChanges();
        }

        return View(getDoublons(dt_doublons));
    }
```